# formula to count how many instances of a row occur with one cell containing a string and the other having its entire content equal to another string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to count the number of times that the cell BN in my spreadsheet contains the string "FP_T" AND the cell BO of the same row contains the string "Step3CallerAndCalleeClassTracesImpliesMethodTracePattern". In other words, I would like to count how many times a row like the one highlighted in yellow and shown in the following picture occurs: 
[image]

I tried to use the formula: =COUNTIFS($BN$:$BN$,"FP_T",$BO$:$BO$,"Step3CallerAndCalleeClassTracesImpliesMethodTracePattern") but it's not working. Note that the cell BN contains the string that I am searching for (FP_T) while the cell BO has its entire content equal to the string that I am searching for.

Comment: Use wildcards: change `"FP_T"` to `"*FP_T*"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("/FP_T",$C$2:$C$4))*($D$2:$D$4="Step3CallerAndCalleeClassTracesImpliesMethodTracePattern"))
```

[image]